# Probability of finding a valid block when cryptocurrency mining

Tags: cryptocurrency

Today I learned that for BTC, the probability of a hash being valid is approximately `1/(D*2^32)`, whereas D denotes to the difficulty. I was wondering if this is also the case for other cryptocurrencies or if this is something specific to BTC or the SHA-256 hash algorithm? If it is different for other cryptocurrencies, are there similar formulas for the probability of a hash being valid?

Comment: This is not really cryptography specific, probably better on the Bitcoin stackexchange. I've asked a moderator to migrate the question there. That said, this is definitely a property of Bitcoin's particular algorithm choices, one can trivially design a different difficulty function. But I'm not a cryptocurrency expert, so I don't know **what** difficulty functions are actually in use for various coins.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus Note that [bitcoin.se] has somewhat recently changed their policy to _only_ accept bitcoin related questions. So they likely won't appreciate such a general question and given that it _is_ about the cryptographic mechanics of cryptocurrencies, I'm inclined to believe it should be on-topic here. [Reference](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1020/87494)

Comment: Some cryptocurrencies don't even mine. So yeah, there's that.